# MouseListener is not triggered when I am clicking

Tags: java, event-handling, awt, mouseevent, mouselistener

MouseListener is not triggered when I am clicking. I first tried it without any labels and panel. It worked just fine as I could see the mouse coodinates and key pressed on my console. Here is the code for it:

```
//Write a program to handle key and mouse event

import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class HandleEvent{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Frame fr = new Frame("HandleEvent");
        fr.setSize(500,500);
        fr.setVisible(true);
        
        fr.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
                System.out.println("(" + e.getX() + ", " + e.getY() + ")");
            }
        });
        
        fr.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
                System.out.println("Key Pressed: " + e.getKeyChar());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to update the labels whenever I click or press key. The keyPressed() function works but my mouseClicked() is not being triggered when I click. Here is the code:

```
//Write a program to handle key and mouse event

import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class HandleEvent{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Frame fr = new Frame("HandleEvent");
        
        Panel pan = new Panel(new FlowLayout());
        
        Label lb1 = new Label("Mouse coordinates: (x, y)", Label.CENTER);
        Label lb2 = new Label("Key Pressed: *Press any key*", Label.CENTER);
        
        pan.add(lb1);
        pan.add(lb2);
        
        fr.add(pan);
        fr.setSize(500,500);
        fr.setVisible(true);
        
        fr.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
                lb1.setText("Mouse coordinates: (" + e.getX() + ", " + e.getY() + ")");
                System.out.println("Mouse clicked!");
                lb1.repaint();
            }
        });
        
        fr.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
                lb2.setText("Key Pressed: " + e.getKeyChar());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I tried fr.setFocusable(true), fr.requestFocus(), fr.setEnabled(true) but it didn't work. I even tried other mouse events but it still didn't work.

Comment: Think about what you’re clicking on.  You’re clicking inside the Frame, but the actual object you’re clicking on is a Label or Panel, not the Frame itself.

Comment: So would he have to register his MouseAdapter to each and every component (Label, Panel, ...), or would it suffice to register it to fr.getContentPane()? What's the solution?

Comment: @Queeg Yes, it is necessary to register a MouseListener on each clickable component.  (This is not true in JavaFX, where each node has a mouseTransparent property.)

Comment: Could fr.getGlassPane() help? After all that's what it is for, isn't it? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html

Comment: I tried adding mouse listener to Panel and now it works! But I don't understand. How is the keyListener working with Frame but mouseListener doesn't?

Comment: The mouse usually applies to whichever screen coordinate the pointer is at. The keyboard does not have this screen coordinate, but it has a focus. This one can only be assigned to 'focusable' components. Thus it has to behave differently than the mouse. See also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html